Trouble proving inequality regarding the modulus of a complex number sum in uniform distribution theorem
I'm currently working through the proof of the theorem stated in Uniform Distribution of Sequences by Harald Niederreiter and L. Kuipers. The theorem states that if $\Delta x_n = x_{n+1} - x_n \rightarrow \theta \in \mathbb{I}$, then the sequence $x_n$ is uniformly distributed modulo 1.
However, I've encountered a stumbling block while trying to prove an inequality related to the modulus of a sum of complex numbers. Specifically, I am trying to show that
$\displaystyle\left| \sum_{n=0}^{q-1} exp(2 \pi i h \theta n) \right| \leq \dfrac{1}{\left| sin(\pi h \theta) \right|}$
where $\theta \in \mathbb{I}$ and $h \in \mathbb{Z}\,,\ h \neq 0$.
I have attempted various approaches but haven't been successful in establishing this inequality. Any insights, suggestions, or alternative proof strategies would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Here is the theorem and it's proof:
First page and the
Second page.

Just replace $h\theta $ by $t$ and use $\sum_{n=0}^{q-1}r^n=\frac{r^q-1}{r-1}$ for $r=e^{2i\pi t}.$

Thank you!
Here is the solution for people like me:
$\left|\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{q-1}e^{2\pi i h \theta n}\right|=\left|\dfrac{e^{2 \pi i h\theta q}-1}{e^{2 \pi i h\theta}-1}\right|\leq\dfrac{\left|e^{2\pi i h\theta q}\right| + 1}{\left| e^{2\pi i h\theta}-1\right|}\leq\dfrac{2}{\left|e^{2\pi i h\theta}-1\right|}$ and since $\dfrac{\left|e^{i \theta}-1\right|}{2}=\left|\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right|$, we get $\left| \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{q-1} e^{2\pi i h\theta n}\right|\leq\dfrac{1}{\left|\sin\pi h\theta\right|}$. Given that $\theta\in\mathbb{I}\Rightarrow\sin\pi h\theta \neq 0$.
